# How to "Show" image with Rails Paperclip

Tags: ruby, rubygems, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

I am creating an image upload application with Rails 5 and Paperclip. I can display the uploaded images perfectly fine in a list view on the index page. I have a "Show" link for each image set up, as well as show route and show method within controller. However, I cannot figure out how to properly display the the image via its :id on the show.html.erb page. Calling the image from <%= image_tag image.avatar.url %> does not work on with displaying on show.html.erb. I simply want to display the individual image on an images/show/:id page after the user clicks the 'show' link from the index page.

Here is my model(this could be the issue...do i need display_url?):

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
has_attached_file :avatar
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar,
:content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
end
```

Here is the Show method in Controller

```
 def show
  @image = Image.find(params[:id])
 end
```

show.html.erb (this code is the issue here)

```
<% image_tag @image.avatar.url %>
```

Here is my image list view in index.html.erb (working 100%):

```
  <% if @images %>
            <% @images.each do |image| %>
              <%= image_tag image.avatar.url %>
              <%= image_tag image.title, {class: "list-group-item"} %>
              <a href="/images/<%= image.id %>">Display</a>
              <a href="/images/edit/<%= image.id %>">Edit</a>
            <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to render image so use `<%= ... %>` instead of `<% %>`

Comment: So <%= image_tag image.avatar.url %>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<% image_tag @image.avatar.url %>
```

Use

```
<%= image_tag @image.avatar.url %>
```

The equals (`=`) symbol is used when we want to display or render anything on the page.

When you write this:

```
<% image_tag @image.avatar.url %>
```

The `image` URL is being retrieved, but is not being rendered to the page.